# How to do chain rule in matrix calculus?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

> $$f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} x^2 + y^2 \\ xy \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$g(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix} g_1 \\ g_2 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 2u -v \\ v-u \end{bmatrix}$$, find $ [f \circ g]'$

I got the derivative matric of $f$:

$$ Df= \begin{bmatrix} 2x & 2y \\ y & x \end{bmatrix}$$

And, I can not figure out the correct derivative matrix of g: should it be $ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial u} \\ \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}$ or  $ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial u}\end{bmatrix}$ for taking  chain rule correctly? Which one is correct and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tangential comment, but this isn't "matrix Calculus", it's just vector calculus, right? The Jacobian and the multivariable chain rule are standard topics in vector calculus.

Comment: Going by the first paragraph in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20matrix%20calculus%20is,especially%20over%20spaces%20of%20matrices.&text=Both%20of%20these%20conventions%20are,(rather%20than%20row%20vectors).) it seems pretty accurate

Comment: Hmm, I think the key phrase in the first sentence of that article is "especially over spaces of matrices". If we're dealing with functions that take a matrix as input, then we're doing matrix calculus. But if we're dealing with functions that take a point in $\mathbb R^n$ as input, then we're just doing vector calculus. At least, that's what I think is the difference between vector calculus and matrix calculus. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is most definitely standard vector calculus... $f,g: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You need the [multivariable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule) $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k}=\sum_j\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial g_j}\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_k}$.

Comment: Oh, I think I got what to do from your comment @J.G. Let me add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat detailed derivation of the chain rule using matrix calculus. We have
\begin{align*}
&f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2\\
&f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}f_1(x,y)\\f_2(x,y)\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x^2+y^2\\xy\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
&g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \\
&g(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}g_1(u,v)\\g_2(u,v)\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}2u-v\\v-u\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial(u,v)}}
> &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\left(g_1,g_2\right)}\,\frac{\partial g}{\partial(u,v)}\\
> &=\begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial g_1}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial g_2}\\
> \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial g_1}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial g_2}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial v}\\
> \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial v}
> \end{bmatrix}\\
> &=\begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial }{\partial g_1}\left(g_1^2+g_2^2\right)&\frac{\partial }{\partial g_2}\left(g_1^2+g_2^2\right)\\
> \frac{\partial}{\partial g_1}\left(g_1g_2\right)&\frac{\partial }{\partial g_2}\left(g_1g_2\right)
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial v}\\
> \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial v}
> \end{bmatrix}\\
> &=\begin{bmatrix}
> 2g_1&2g_2\\g_2&g_1
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2&-1\\-1&1
> \end{bmatrix}\\
> &=\begin{bmatrix}
> 2(2u-v)&2(v-u)\\v-u&2u-v
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2&-1\\-1&1
> \end{bmatrix}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\begin{bmatrix}
> 10u-6v&-6u+4v\\
> -4u+3v&3u-2v
> \end{bmatrix}}
> \end{align*}

A crosscheck by using @PierreCarres result. We have
\begin{align*}
(f\circ g)(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}
(2u-v)^2+(v-u)^2\\
(2u-v)(v-u)
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
5u^2-6uv+2v^2\\
-2u^2+3uv-v^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

> It follows
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial (u,v)}}
> &=\frac{\partial}{\partial (u,v)}\begin{bmatrix}
> 5u^2-6uv+2v^2\\
> -2u^2+3uv-v^2
> \end{bmatrix}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\begin{bmatrix}
> 10u-6v&-6u+4v\\
> -4u+3v&3u-2v
> \end{bmatrix}}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the result above.

Comment: Where did you get the notation $\partial(u_1,u_2)$ I think I've seen something similar for jacobian determinant but not sure

Comment: @Buraian: Most often we are used to write a single letter boldface $\mathbb{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ when writing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbb{x}}$ for economical reasons. Here I just wanted to keep your coordinate notation. There is no substantial difference.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of telling you which is the correct formula for the Jacobian of $g$, let me just tell you that
$$
(f\circ g)(u,v)= f(g(u,v))=\begin{bmatrix}
(2u-v)^2+(v-u)^2\\(2u-v)(v-u)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, you can compute the derivatives of $f$ with respect to $u,v$ and compare to what you would get by using each of the versions of the Jacobian of $g$ that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on J.G.s comment, call $(u,v) = (\nu_1,\nu_2)$ then we have in tensor notation:

$$ \frac{\partial f_i \circ g}{\partial \nu^j} = \sum \frac{ \partial f_i}{\partial g^k} \frac{\partial g^k}{ \partial \nu^j}$$

Setting $ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial g^k} = a_k^i $ and $ \frac{\partial g^k}{\partial \nu^j} = b_j^k$ it becomes clear that the matrix of partial derivatives i.e: $Df \circ g$ takes the following form:

$$ D f  \circ g = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial g^1} &  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial g^2} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial g^1} &  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial g^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial g^1}{\partial \nu^1}  &  \frac{\partial g^1}
{\partial \nu^1} 
\\ \frac{\partial g^2}{\partial \nu^1}  & \frac{\partial g^2}{\partial \nu^2} \end{bmatrix} $$